# Adding page titles to existing pages beneath site title

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

My client has an existing banner site title and after 7+ years, they now want beneath the page banner text another line citing what the page title is.  I'm trying to avoid having to go into each and every page to add a line of text and came up with the following solution.  It isn't perfect (nor does it have to be) but do you see any unforseen issues wtih this approach?

```
<cfparam name="url.CurrentPage" default="">
<div id="wideheader">
<div id="wideheadermain">
    <h1 id="title">
    <div class="PageBannerText">Technology Lab
    <span id="CurrentPage"><cfswitch expression="#url.CurrentPage#">
        <cfcase value="Update">
            Update Project Data
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="Tracker">
            Project Tracker
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="ProjectLog">
            Project Log
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="Portfolio">
            Project Portfolio
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="Links">
            Related Links
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="Coordinator">
            Coordinator Space
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="Request">
            Project Request
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="Viewer">
            Project Tracker Read-Only
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="LabMgr">
            Lab Manager
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="Architect">
            Architect Module
        </cfcase>
        <cfdefaultcase>
            #url.CurrentPage#
        </cfdefaultcase>
    </cfswitch> #cookie.CurrentPage#</span>
        </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

I can add the code above to my header page and then in the main nav menu, add the following code which will set the sub page title:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="Proj/TrackerMenu.cfm?CurrentPage=Project Tracker">Project Tracker</a></li>
    <li><a href="Proj/RequestCopyOrAdd.cfm?CurrentPage=Request a Project">Request a Project</a></li>
    <li><a href="Proj/ViewerMenu.cfm?CurrentPage=Project Viewer">Project Viewer</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I know this wont be perfect but I believe this will cover 90-95% of the site.

The other idea I had was to wrap the sub page banner text with a span tag and give it an ID and then use jQUery to set the text.  I could write a routine to evaluate the current URL and then set the sub page banner text accordingly.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simpler solution is to store the titles in a struct and then do a lookup.

i.e. put this inside onApplicationStart:

```
<cfset Application.PageTitles = 
    { 'Update'    : 'Update Project Data'
    , 'Tracker'   : 'Projet Tracker'
    ...
    , 'LabMgr'    : 'Lab Manager'
    , 'Architect' : 'Architect Module'
    }/>
```

*<sup>(NOTE: If you're on CF9 or earlier, you need to use `=` instead of `:` there. CF10, and all versions of Railo and OpenBD support use of either `:` or `=` in inline structs.)</sup>*

Then replace your switch/case block with this:

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(Application.PageTitles,Url.CurrentPage)>
    <cfset PageTitle = Application.PageTitles[Url.CurrentPage] />
<cfelse>
    <cfset PageTitle = Url.CurrentPage />
</cfif>

#HtmlEditFormat(PageTitle)#
```

You can use something similar in your menus, so you don't need to update the title in multiple places.

Note also the use of [HtmlEditFormat](http://cfdocs.org/HtmlEditFormat) to prevent possible HTML/script injection.

You should also add that to the cookie variable, and any other user-supplied variables (plus any variables not guaranteed not to have characters that might change the HTML).

Comment: I like the idea of placing this in a struct and +1 for the HTMLEditFormat.  I usually remember that after a trouble ticket is placed.  LOL